# How to align buttons no matter how content of previous elements changes?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to align some buttons no matter how the content of previous elements changes. [This](https://codepen.io/lmiguelvargasf/pen/dqYxgp) is the markup that I currently have.

I currently have the buttons at the bottom not aligned as shown in the following image:

[image]

Notice that the buttons REQUEST DEMO are not properly aligned, so what I want is no matter the content in the previous `p` element is, they are aligned as shown in the following image:

[image]

Notice that here I used the same text to make it look aligned, but I want the buttons to be aligned no matter what the content of the text is.

I also need this functionality to be responsive since I am using bootstrap and for smaller screens, it shows two elements or one element per line.

I was thinking to add a `min-height` or `max-height` in the CSS, but this hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are using bootstrap correctly? This should not be a problem with using bootstrap. If you need 4 'sections' on one row use 'col-sm-3' for all ?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri, I am kind of new to Bootstrap, so if you have any idea on how to solve please feel free to add it the provided CodePen.

Comment: When somebody downvotes could at least explain why they are upvoting? Stack Overflow is considered an aggressive place for people who just start learning certain technologies, and these are the kind of people who are damaging the reputation of this site by downvoting without providing reasons.

Comment: I agree with @Imiguelvargasf I have run into the same problem. Grumpy old coders who have nothing better to do than to downvote without reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code and see if this is what you are looking for.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for `flexbox`

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  display: -ms-flexbox; 
  display: flex; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-md-6 {
  flex: 1; 
  margin-right: 10px; 
  padding: 50px;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this. The easiest way would be using flexbox, here's a snippet example https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Another way you could do it is having a fixed height for every column, and absolute position the button to the bottom and maybe add some padding to the content so the text never overlaps the button.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class `.btn-box`to the buttons and  and this class `.padbot` to the box

**CSS**

```
.btn-box{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.padbot{
  padding-bottom: 80px; // Adjust as your needs
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/173703/)**

Comment: Simple, get padding- bottom to the box

Comment: what box? ... do you mean the `btn-box`?

Comment: @LuisPA, honestly I don't see that this solves the problem. I still see the buttons over text that previously was above them.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf  did you see the button overlapping the text? Are the buttons not aligned?

Comment: It seems that the button is still very close. Try adding margin to the top of .btn-box

Comment: Just add more padding, 80px was an example

Comment: The padding you added to .padbot is incorret to moving the button. The price above the button is still too close when you increase padding. you need to add margin to move the price away from the button

Comment: Is not to move the button, is to not overlap the text... to move the button use .btn-box the rule bottom ex: bottom: 30px;

Comment: I agree with @JulianSilvestri, This is not working properly I tried in my CodePen, and it doesn't solve the problem. In addition, this does not work when you have just one element row.